# Range slider control in c# xaml

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-8, custom-controls, winrt-xaml

I need to create a slider control with two thumbs[range slider].
can anybody give me the idea to modify default slider control inthat way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i created a custom slider control with two slider.

This link helps me 
http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2012/01/21/Building-C-custom-controls-in-WinRT-Metro.aspx
**MainPage.xaml:**

```
<newslider:SimpleSlider x:Name="PriceSlider"  Width="650" LowerValueChanged="PriceSlider_LowerValueChanged" UpperValueChanged="PriceSlider_UpperValueChanged"/>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs:**

```
 private void PriceSlider_UpperValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 }

 private void PriceSlider_LowerValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 }
```

Here is the control code :

**Generic.xaml:**

```
<Style TargetType="ctrl:RangeSliderSlider">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ctrl:SimpleSlider">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Grid Height="15">
                        <Border Height="15"
                            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                            Background="DarkGray"/>
                        <Canvas Margin="0"
                            MinHeight="8">
                            <Rectangle x:Name="PART_Rectangle_Middle" 
                                   Height="15"
                                   Fill="LightBlue" />
                            <Thumb x:Name="PART_Thumb_Lower"
                               Width="15"
                               Height="15" Background="White" />
                            <Thumb x:Name="PART_Thumb_Upper"
                               Width="15"
                               Height="15" Background="White" />
                        </Canvas>
                    </Grid>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,-15,0">
                        <ItemsControl  x:Name="PART_ItemsControl_RangeControl" 
                                       Canvas.ZIndex="1"                                                                                  
                                        >
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid Width="{Binding Tag,ElementName=PART_ItemsControl_RangeControl}" >
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <TextBlock Text="|" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="Gray" FontSize="10"/>
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Foreground="Gray" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Margin="{Binding RangeMargin}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding RangeValue}" FontSize="12"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                        <Grid x:Name="PART_LastMark_Grid" Width="{Binding Tag,ElementName=PART_ItemsControl_RangeControl}" >
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Text="|" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="-4,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="Gray" FontSize="10"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="PART_Lastmark_TextBlock"  Grid.Row="1" Margin="-4,0,0,0" Foreground="Gray" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextAlignment="Left" FontSize="12"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**RangeSlider.cs:**

```
using RangeSlider;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes;

[TemplatePart(Name = ThumbPartName_Upper, Type = typeof(Thumb))]
[TemplatePart(Name = ThumbPartNameLower, Type = typeof(Thumb))]
[TemplatePart(Name = RectanglePartName, Type = typeof(Rectangle))]
[TemplatePart(Name = RangeValueControl, Type = typeof(ItemsControl))]
[TemplatePart(Name = RangeLastMarkValue, Type = typeof(TextBlock))]
public class SimpleSlider : Control
{
    private const string ThumbPartName_Upper = "PART_Thumb_Upper";
    private const string RectanglePartName = "PART_Rectangle_Middle";
    private const string ThumbPartNameLower = "PART_Thumb_Lower";
    private const string RangeValueControl = "PART_ItemsControl_RangeControl";
    private const string RangeLastMarkValue = "PART_Lastmark_TextBlock";

    private Thumb _upperThumb;
    private Thumb _lowerthumb;
    private Rectangle _middleFillRectangle;
    private ItemsControl _scaleValueControl;
    private TextBlock _lastmarkTextblock;
    private int _interval;
    private double _sectionValue;
    private double _interval_width;

    public event EventHandler LowerValueChanged;
    public event EventHandler UpperValueChanged;

    #region Properties

    private bool isThumbSelected = true;

    public bool IsThumbSelected
    {
        get { return isThumbSelected; }
        set { isThumbSelected = value; IsThumb_Selected = value; }
    }

    public static bool IsThumb_Selected { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Dependency Properties

    public double Minimum
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(MinimumProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MinimumProperty, value); }
    }

    public double Maximum
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(MaximumProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MaximumProperty, value); }
    }

    public double LowerValue
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(LowerValueProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(LowerValueProperty, value);
            RangeEventArgs e = new RangeEventArgs() { NewValue = value };
            if (LowerValueChanged != null)
                LowerValueChanged(this, e);
        }
    }

    public double UpperValue
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(UpperValueProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(UpperValueProperty, value);
            RangeEventArgs e = new RangeEventArgs() { NewValue = value };
            if (UpperValueChanged != null)
                UpperValueChanged(this, e);
        }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for UpperValue.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty UpperValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("UpperValue", typeof(double), typeof(SimpleSlider), new PropertyMetadata(0.0, UpperValuePropertyChanged));


    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for LowerValue.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LowerValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("LowerValue", typeof(double), typeof(SimpleSlider), new PropertyMetadata(0.0, LowerValuePropertyChanged));

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Minimum.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MinimumProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Minimum", typeof(double), typeof(SimpleSlider), new PropertyMetadata(0.0));


    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Maximum.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MaximumProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Maximum", typeof(double), typeof(SimpleSlider), new PropertyMetadata(0.0));

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for RangeCollection.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RangeCollectionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("RangeCollection", typeof(List<Range>), typeof(SimpleSlider), new PropertyMetadata(null));


    public List<Range> RangeCollection
    {
        get { return (List<Range>)GetValue(RangeCollectionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RangeCollectionProperty, value); }
    }


    public double Division
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(DivisionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DivisionProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Division.  This enables binding scale division width, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DivisionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Division", typeof(double), typeof(SimpleSlider), new PropertyMetadata(0));

    public string LastMark
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(LastMarkProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LastMarkProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LastMarkProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("LastMark", typeof(string), typeof(SimpleSlider), new PropertyMetadata(""));


    public int MinimumInterval
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(MinimumIntervalProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MinimumIntervalProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MinimumInterval.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MinimumIntervalProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MinimumInterval", typeof(int), typeof(SimpleSlider), new PropertyMetadata(5));


    public int MaximumInteraval
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(MaximumInteravalProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MaximumInteravalProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MaximumInteraval.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MaximumInteravalProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MaximumInteraval", typeof(int), typeof(SimpleSlider), new PropertyMetadata(15));

    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// When overridden in a derived class, is invoked whenever application code or internal processes call <see cref="M:System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ApplyTemplate"/>.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        this._upperThumb = this.GetTemplateChild(ThumbPartName_Upper) as Thumb;
        if (this._upperThumb != null)
        {
            this._upperThumb.DragDelta += this.Thumb_DragDelta;
        }

        this._lowerthumb = this.GetTemplateChild(ThumbPartNameLower) as Thumb;
        if (_lowerthumb != null)
        {
            this._lowerthumb.DragDelta += this.Thumb1_DragDelta;
        }
        this._middleFillRectangle = this.GetTemplateChild(RectanglePartName) as Rectangle;

        this._scaleValueControl = this.GetTemplateChild(RangeValueControl) as ItemsControl;
        this._lastmarkTextblock = this.GetTemplateChild(RangeLastMarkValue) as TextBlock;

        this.SizeChanged += new SizeChangedEventHandler(SimpleSlider_SizeChanged);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method for displying values in the range slider
    /// </summary>
    public void PopulateScaleValues()
    {
        _sectionValue = Minimum;
        bool isDivFound = false;
        for (int i = MaximumInteraval; i >= MinimumInterval; i--)
        {
            if (!isDivFound)
            {
                if (0 == Math.IEEERemainder(Maximum, i))
                {
                    _interval = i;
                    isDivFound = true;
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        _interval_width = Maximum / _interval;
        var totalSize = this.ActualWidth;
        Division = totalSize / _interval;
        this._scaleValueControl.Tag = Division;
        if (RangeCollection == null)
            RangeCollection = new List<Range>();
        RangeCollection.Add(new Range { RangeValue = _sectionValue });
        for (int i = 0; i < _interval; i++)
        {
            _sectionValue = _sectionValue + _interval_width;
            RangeCollection.Add(new Range { RangeValue = _sectionValue });
        }

        this._scaleValueControl.ItemsSource = RangeCollection;
        LastMark = (_sectionValue + _interval_width).ToString();
        this._lastmarkTextblock.Text = RangeCollection[_interval].RangeValue.ToString();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when size changed.
    /// </summary>
    private void SimpleSlider_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewSize.Width != e.PreviousSize.Width)
        {
            //this.UpdateControls();
            //this.UpdateControls1();
            //PopulateScaleValues();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when value changed.
    /// </summary>
    private static void OnValueChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Simple version: no coercion involved.
        var customSlider = (SimpleSlider)dependencyObject;
        if (IsThumb_Selected)
        {
            customSlider.UpperValue = Convert.ToDouble(e.NewValue);
        }
        else
        {
            customSlider.LowerValue = Convert.ToDouble(e.NewValue);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called  when lower value changed
    /// </summary>
    private static void LowerValuePropertyChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var customSlider = (SimpleSlider)dependencyObject;
        customSlider.UpperValue = Math.Max(customSlider.UpperValue, customSlider.LowerValue);
        customSlider.UpdateControls1();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called When Upper value changed
    /// </summary>
    private static void UpperValuePropertyChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var customSlider = (SimpleSlider)dependencyObject;
        customSlider.LowerValue = Math.Min(customSlider.UpperValue, customSlider.LowerValue);
        customSlider.UpdateControls();
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the DragDelta event of the Thumb control.
    /// </summary>
    private void Thumb_DragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        IsThumbSelected = true;
        this._lowerthumb.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        this._upperThumb.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        var pixelDiff = e.HorizontalChange;
        var currentLeft = Canvas.GetLeft(this._upperThumb);

        // trying to drag too far left
        if ((currentLeft + pixelDiff) < 0)
        {
            this.UpperValue = 0;
        }
        // trying to drag too far right
        else if ((currentLeft + pixelDiff + this._upperThumb.ActualWidth) > this.ActualWidth)
        {
            this.UpperValue = this.Maximum;
        }
        else
        {
            var totalSize = this.ActualWidth;
            var ratioDiff = pixelDiff / totalSize;
            var rangeSize = this.Maximum - this.Minimum;
            var rangeDiff = rangeSize * ratioDiff;
            this.UpperValue += rangeDiff;

        }
        if (this.LowerValue == this.UpperValue && e.HorizontalChange < 0)
        {

            this._lowerthumb.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            this._upperThumb.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        if (this.LowerValue == this.Minimum && this.LowerValue == this.UpperValue)
        {

            this._lowerthumb.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            this._upperThumb.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the DragDelta event of the Thumb control.
    /// </summary>
    private void Thumb1_DragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        this._lowerthumb.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        this._upperThumb.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        IsThumbSelected = false;

        var pixelDiff = e.HorizontalChange;
        var currentLeft = Canvas.GetLeft(this._lowerthumb);

        // trying to drag too far left
        if ((currentLeft + pixelDiff) < 0)
        {
            this.LowerValue = 0;
        }


        // trying to drag too far right
        else if ((currentLeft + pixelDiff + this._lowerthumb.ActualWidth) > this.ActualWidth)
        {
            this.LowerValue = this.Maximum;
        }
        else
        {
            var totalSize = this.ActualWidth;
            var ratioDiff = pixelDiff / totalSize;
            var rangeSize = this.Maximum - this.Minimum;
            var rangeDiff = rangeSize * ratioDiff;

            this.LowerValue += rangeDiff;
        }
        if (this.LowerValue == this.UpperValue && e.HorizontalChange > 0)
        {

            this._lowerthumb.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            this._upperThumb.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        if (this.LowerValue == this.Maximum && this.LowerValue==this.UpperValue)
        {

            this._lowerthumb.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            this._upperThumb.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Updates the controls.
    /// </summary>
    public void UpdateControls()
    {
        double halfTheThumbWith = 0;

        if (this._upperThumb != null)
        {
            halfTheThumbWith = this._upperThumb.ActualWidth / 2;
        }

        double totalSize = this.ActualWidth - halfTheThumbWith * 2;

        double ratio = totalSize / (this.Maximum - this.Minimum);

        if (this._upperThumb != null)
        {
            Canvas.SetLeft(this._upperThumb, ratio * this.UpperValue);
        }

        if (this._middleFillRectangle != null)
        {
            Canvas.SetLeft(this._middleFillRectangle, ratio * this.LowerValue);
            this._middleFillRectangle.Width = ratio * (this.UpperValue - this.LowerValue) + halfTheThumbWith;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Updates the controls.
    /// </summary>
    public void UpdateControls1()
    {
        double halfTheThumbWith = 0;

        if (this._lowerthumb != null)
        {
            halfTheThumbWith = this._upperThumb.ActualWidth / 2;
        }

        double totalSize = this.ActualWidth - halfTheThumbWith * 2;

        double ratio = totalSize / (this.Maximum - this.Minimum);

        if (this._lowerthumb != null)
        {
            Canvas.SetLeft(this._lowerthumb, ratio * this.LowerValue);
        }

        if (this._middleFillRectangle != null)
        {
            Canvas.SetLeft(this._middleFillRectangle, ratio * this.LowerValue);
            this._middleFillRectangle.Width = ratio * (this.UpperValue - this.LowerValue) + halfTheThumbWith;
        }
    }
}
```

**Range.cs Model:**

```
public class Range
{
    public double RangeValue { get; set; }

    public Thickness RangeMargin
    {
        get
        {
            if (RangeValue.ToString().Length == 1)
            {
                return new Thickness(-1, 0, -1, 0);
            }
            else if (RangeValue.ToString().Length == 2)
            {
                return new Thickness(-5, 0, -5, 0);
            }
            else if (RangeValue.ToString().Length == 3)
            {
                return new Thickness(-7, 0, -7, 0);
            }
            else if (RangeValue.ToString().Length == 4)
            {
                return new Thickness(-9, 0, -9, 0);
            }

            else
                return new Thickness(-1, 0, -1, 0);
        }

    }
}
```

**RangeEventArgs.cs:**

```
public class RangeEventArgs :EventArgs
{
    public double NewValue { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi! how is build RangeSliderSlider? Thanks!

Comment: How can I prevent to coincide two thumbs in each other? I want to put minimum range.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can look at this article.

http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Creating_a_Range_Slider_in_Silverlight_and_some_of_the_binding_gotchas_in_SL3_.aspx

In my opinion is pretty clear described. Sample maybe it's not very good-looking but I hope it's not the most important thing. Enjoy!

Comment: @asitis - Sorry I don't understand what you mean excatly?